# Sustituir las comillas simples por dobles en una petición POST en Python (requests) que como Payload usa un diccionario

Tags: python, diccionarios, requests

Estoy generando una solicitud de login desde Python, request:

```
login = sesion.post(URL, data=payload, headers=header)
```

Lo que debo generar es esto como body de la petición:

```
{
"operationName":"Login",
"variables":{
  "id":"UserId,"country":"ES","lang":"en","password":"PASSWORD"},
}
```

Pero Python me genera el payload con comillas símples, y esto provoca error en el servidor, que espera comillas dobles.
He probado a crear el payload como un string de texto, pero también provoca un error de servidor.
¿Alguna manera de indicar a Python que utilice las comillas dobles como separador de un diccionario? o ¿Alguna otra sugerencia?
Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!!

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que Python te genera el payload con comillas simples? ¿Dónde lo ves así? Que yo sepa requests convierte el payload a form-encoded, Entiendo que tu variable `payload` es de tipo `dict`. ¿Necesitas recibirlo como JSON?

Comment: Seguro no lo estoy de nada ; ). Imprimo símplemente la variable y aunque yo la haya definido con comillas dobles, me la imprime con comillas sencillas. Además he provocado el fallo repitiendo respuestas válidas cambiando las comillas y se reproduce el "error interno". Si, yo defino payload = {} y aunque los separadores que uso en la definición son ", me los imprime y supongo envía con '. Entiendo que los tiros van por el formato json, voy a ver si tratándolo como json lo envía con las ".

Answer (score 1):

ya está. Al final iba por el tema de json.
Le paso como `payload=json.dumps(payload1)`

Con esto lo imprime (y supongo envía) con comillas dobles y ya me valida.
Gracias!